# Make MySQL use index for sorting, but not in WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql

I have a query that simplifies to

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE field > 5
ORDER BY field DESC
```

where `field>5` matches more than half the records. I have an index on `field`, but MySQL isn't using it because too many records satisfy the condition. Is it possible to use the index only for the order, but not the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Why would the index be useful for the ordering? What would you achieve? Do you know how indexes work at all?

Comment: Why wouldn't the index be useful for filtering?

Comment: @GolezTrol In some cases if selectivity of data is low usage of index can be avoided by optimizer.

Comment: @N.B. Wouldn't an index speed up ordering?

Comment: @Linksku - not necessarily. MySQL skips using indexes because it's *faster* to work without it sometimes.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I know, but why would you try to influence that. Usually the optimizer is right in that decision.

Comment: @GolezTrol, Of course you are right. I just answered to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the simple answer is: there is no point in doing so, even if possible. The database optimizer decides when to use the index depending whether it's going to enhance the performance or not.